# detect holes in css-grid auto-flow dense layout and adjust then adjust element sizes

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-grid

With css-grid, auto-flow dense can adjust the layout of elements by inserting elements out of order in order to create density. In some cases there will be gaps, because there is no appropriate sized element that will fit the space.  My question is whether I can detect this condition after layout and if so how? Using JavaScript or anything else would be fine.

Edit: My goal is to create a completely filled in grid by some means- the best being to adjust the size of the component elements of the grid. I would prefer a grid without variable sized columns *and* rows. The use case is a newspaper which can layout a front page based on some abstract weight for each article that reflects its importance or popularity. To be clear, the grid element does not need to contain all of the content.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is how to identify unoccupied grid cells.

I don't think that's possible because without a grid area occupying the space, an unoccupied cell is just an abstract container designed only for use by the layout algorithm.

But that's my best guess at the moment.

Here are two key sections in the grid spec for anybody wanting to look into this:

- [7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
- [8.5. Grid Item Placement Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo)

Comment: Thanks. I revised the post to clarify that while I am asking about unoccupied cells, the goal is to fill those holes!